# How to upload file to (shared drive) with google api v3?

Tags: c#, google-api

How to upload file or folder to (shared drive) with google api v3 by c# ?

> I tried this but not working, still uploaded in my drive not shared drive

```
var Folder = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File()
{
    Name = fName,
    MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder",
    DriveId=driveID
};


Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File result = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File();
var request = service.Files.Create(Folder);

request.Fields = "name,id,webViewLink";
request.SupportsAllDrives = true;
result = request.Execute();

Console.WriteLine("'" + Folder.Name + "' folder created");
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote `Parents = new List<string> { driveID }` 
instead of `DriveId=driveID` and it worked